# How can I get design attribute values from a specific Word or Excel document?

Tags: c#, office-interop

Is it possible to get the design attribute values FROM a specific document? If so, what method will I use, and how?

Example:

I have file.docx, then that file.docx has a text with a font Tahoma, size 74 and styled bold and italic. Now, I want to get the value of attribute to where the font is set, the size and the style (note: value, not the attribute). If this is possible, will it be also for styled tables, etc?

Answer (score 0):

For a Word document:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

        namespace ConsoleApplication1
        {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {

                    Application application = new Application();
                    application.Visible = false;


                    Document document = application.Documents.Open(@"C:\file.docx", Type.Missing, true);

                    // Loop through all words in the document.
                    int count = document.Words.Count;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
                    {
                        string text = document.Words[i].Text; //you can validate if string.IsNullOrEmpty....
                        string fontName = document.Words[i].Font.Name;
                        string bold = document.Words[i].Font.Bold.ToString();
                        string fontSize = document.Words[i].Font.Size.ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine("Word {0} = {1} -- Font:{2}, Size: {3}, Bold:{4}", i, text, fontName, fontSize, bold);
                    }


                    application.Quit();

                    Console.ReadLine();

                   }
            }
        }
```

Excel Document:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...

     static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Application application = new Application();
                application.Visible = false;
                string filePath = @"C:\excel.xlsx";

                var book = application.Workbooks.Open(filePath, Type.Missing, true);

                Workbook workBook = application.Workbooks.Open(filePath,
                                                                Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                                Type.Missing, Type.Missing);



                foreach (Worksheet item in workBook.Sheets)
                {
                    foreach (Range cell in item.Cells)
                    {
                        //Navigate huge options... 
                        //.Borders
                        //.Style
                        //... 
                    }

                }



                workBook.Close(false, filePath, null);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBook);

                application.Quit();

                Console.ReadLine();


            }
```

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for your answer. Is this the same for styled tables? How about if I will not going to use Words? I will get my design from a 'designed' template and from there i'll put my content?

Comment: Hi. I added an example for excel. It is very extensive and varied the way they are designing a template. This example will allow you to open documents, and loop elements... but to find what you need I invite you to investigate http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms262200.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Keep in mind that if you develop a desktop application and will use the client's office dlls, you may not all have the same version. If possible, use a server for this process... if you want to avoid a headache.  The answer is that you can get all the data, requires narrow the variables you are looking at your documents